# Casting to a Class which is determined at run-time

Tags: java, generics, reflection, casting, reification

I have a method `fetchObjects(String)` that is expected to return an array of `Contract` business objects. The `className` parameter tells me what kind of business objects I should return (of course this doesn't make sense in this construed case because I already said I will return `Contract`s, but it's basically the situation I have in my real scenario). So I get the set of entries from somewhere and load the class of the collection's entries (the type of which is specified by `className`).

Now I need to construct the array to return, so I use `Set`'s `toArray(T[])` method. Using reflection, I build myself an empty Contracts array. *But,* this gives me a value of static type `Object`! So next I need to cast it to the appropriate type, which in this case is `Contract[]` (see "asterisk-underlined" part in the listing below).

My question is: Is there a way, and how, to cast to `Contract[]` as I do in the listing, *but determining the type of the array elements (`Contract`) only through `className`* (or `entriesType`)? In other words, what I'd like to do is basically casting like this: `(entriesType[]) valueWithStaticTypeObject`, where entriesType be replaced by the class specified through the `classname` parameter, i.e. `Contract`.

Is this somehow inherently impossible, or can it be done somehow? Maybe using generics?

```
package xx.testcode;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class TypedArrayReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Contract[] contracts = fetchObjects("Contract");
            System.out.println(contracts.length);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
    }

    static Contract[] fetchObjects(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> entriesType = Class.forName("xx.testcode."+className);
        Set<?> entries = ObjectManager.getEntrySet(className); 
        return entries.toArray( 
                (Contract[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                /********/          entriesType, entries.size()) );
    }
}

class Contract { } // business object

class ObjectManager {
    static Set<?> getEntrySet(String className) {
        if (className.equals("Contract"))
            return new HashSet<Contract>();
        return null; // Error
    }
}
```

Thanks.

---

**Update:** Using the type-safe method `toArray`, taken from [CodeIdol](http://codeidol.com/java/javagenerics/Reification/The-Principle-of-Truth-in-Advertising/), I updated my `fetchObjects` method thus:

```
static Contract[] fetchObjects(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> entriesType = Class.forName("xx.testcode."+className);
    Set<?> entries = ObjectManager.getEntrySet(className);
    return toArray(entries, entriesType); // compile error
    // -> "method not applicable for (Set<capture#3-of ?>, Class<capture#4-of ?>)"
}

public static <T> T[] toArray(Collection<T> c, Class<T> k) {
    T[] a = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(k, c.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (T x : c)
        a[i++] = x;
    return a;
}
```

What do I need to do to get rid of the compiler error quoted in the comment? Do I absolutely have to specify `Set<Contract>` in the return type of my `getEntrySet` method so that this can work? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: How to you handle when the class entriesType is not a subclass of Contract?

Comment: entriesType is *not* necessarily a subtype of Contract. It could be Pet, Friend, Hobby - anything that you might have a collection of. In my example case a Customer would have a collection of Contracts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the class as the parameter rather then the class name.

```
   static <T extends Contract> T[] buildArray(Class<T> clazz){
     ArrayList<T> l=new ArrayList<T>();
     return l.toArray((T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, l.size()));
   }
```

EDIT: (after read Yang comment)

No, You cannot use generic type with the value of a variable.

Comment: This is pretty impressive! However the thing is that I *don't* want to hard-codedly specify the Contract class (the business object could just as well be House or Pet, depending on the method parameter className). The right class needs to be determined from the className parameter.

Comment: Since the caller would have to know what type of object he expects, anyway, why not pass in the Class object instead of the name? I don't get what advantage the name has.

Comment: Cf. my comment to Milhous' answer.

Answer (score 1):

So why not use

```
static <T> T[] buildArray(Class<T> clazz){
ArrayList<T> l=new ArrayList<T>();
return l.toArray((T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, l.size()));
}
```

Note. Modified the code from above.

Comment: I think he may wants that the generics <T> is base on the value of "String className", without a typed/generics/class parameter.

Comment: Exactly. In the real scenario, I need to use reflection to get the name of the type, e.g. I get "Contract" from reflection and then load the class with this name.

Comment: You cannot typecast to a type which is unknown at compile-time.  Typecasting is a compile-time issue.  Generics is just a way of parameterizing the typecast, to let the compiler propagate type-information from one part of the code to another.  But it still needs to be known to the compiler.